# SQL Server Bulk Insert CSV - Unexpected EOF

Tags: sql-server, csv, bulkinsert, bcp

I am using SQL Server 2019, and I am attempting to import a `.csv` file, but I'm getting EOF errors.

First attempt was using Bulk Insert. The field terminator is comma and the row terminator is CRLF. I have confirmed this with Notepad++ and a hex editor.

Below is the code that I am using. If I use the datafiletype as char, I get the error:

> Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file.
>
> Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
> The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
>
> Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 6
> Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

If I don't use the datafiletype = 'char' then it imports but the last column contains the entire second row as if it doesn't see the row terminator.

```
Bulk Insert #temp 
From 'D:\myfile.csv'
with
    (rowterminator='0x0A',
     fieldterminator=',',
     datafiletype = 'char')
```

I have also tried using BCP and I get "Unexpected EOF encountered in BCP data-file.

```
bcp MyDatabase.dbo.MyTable in D:\myfile.csv -f D:\Import-T.fmt -T
```

If I open the CSV in Excel, it properly puts everything into the proper columns and rows, so Excel can see the row and column terminators, but BCP and Bulk Insert are having problems.

Can anyone help point out where I am going wrong? I feel like I have tried every possible way to import this file in? I greatly appreciate any and all help that this forum can provide.

Thank you in advance,
RW

Comment: `0x0A` is just a LF, not CR

Comment: To add to @Stu's comment, `0x0D0A` would be Carriage Return, Line Feed.

Comment: I have updated it to 0x0D0A and the same result.  I have tried every variation of 0x0A, 0x0D0A, \n, \r\n, etc. and I get the same "Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file."

Comment: Have you opened the file and manually checked it's actually correct, using something like notepad++

Comment: I have double checked the file with Notepad++ showing all characters as well as a hex editor.

Comment: I have tried this code and I get this errorBulk Insert #temp 
    From 'D:\myfile.csv'
    with(
    format='csv',
    FieldQuote='"',
    FieldTerminator=',',
    RowTerminator='0x0D0A'
    )

Msg 4879, Level 16, State 1, Line 24
Bulk load failed due to invalid column value in CSV data file D:\myfile.csv in row 1, column 10.

Comment: If you're using Notepad++, look at the Encoding (it has it's own menu entry). If it is UTF-8-BOM try changing it to UTF-8 , save the file, and try again. BCP is, unfortunately and frustratingly, very picky about Encoding.

Comment: @BrianStork, the original file shows UTF-8.  I am thoroughly confused.

Comment: You need to divide & conquer. Save half the data to a new file, does that import, continue until you don't have any errors and narrow it down.

Comment: @Stu, I have tried that as well.  I deleted all but the top 15 rows and it's the same issue.  This is the third file from this company, same results.  I feel like the issue is in the file since BCP and Bulk Insert both have EOF errors,  but I can't definitively point them to where the error is in their file for them to correct.

Comment: In your hex editor can you see any Control-Z/EOF characters (0x1A)?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, I did a search and I didn't see any 0x1A

Comment: To add some additional details, the temp table is 17 columns all varchar(max).  The roses in the file have varying columns.  Some may have 5 columns and others may have all 17.  It should import the row columns until it hits a row terminator and then start a new row and leave the remaining columns in that row null.  I am doing a similar process with a different file and it works perfectly for that file.

Comment: _The roses in the file have varying columns. Some may have 5 columns and others may have all 17._ That's a fairly significant thing that `bulk insert` doesn't support - all rows need to have the same number of columns in them, even if they're empty values. Your other file might have imported without error messages, but if you look at the imported data I expect you'll find that the "short rows" will have the data from the next row running in to them.

Comment: @alwayslearning, I am able to do that just fine in another file.  I have checked and it will properly import the columns till it hits a row terminator and then start a new row.  I used to think that it needed empty holding spaces but it worked perfectly.  Now, if the missing column is in the middle it needs a placeholder but if it’s at the end, the row terminator tells the bulk insert to start a new row, regardless if that row had all of the columns.  So it does work, just not on this particular file for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

The bcp and bulk insert tools do not support "ragged" files. Each row in a data file must have the same number of columns, even if some of those columns are blank. Rows that have less columns will cause the process to lose sync and the data from the next line will be run into the current (short) row.

Consider the following CSV file which should have 17 columns in each row, but only five in the second data row:

```
col01,col02,col03,col04,col05,col06,col07,col08,col09,col10,col11,col12,col13,col14,col15,col16,col17
alph01,alph02,alph03,alph04,alph05,alph06,alph07,alph08,alph09,alph10,alph11,alph12,alph13,alph14,alph15,alph16,alph17
brav01,brav02,brav03,brav04,brav05
char01,char02,char03,char04,char05,char06,char07,char08,char09,char10,char11,char12,char13,char14,char15,char16,char17
```

If we attempt to import the above file:

```sql
drop table if exists dbo.CsvImport;

create table dbo.CsvImport (
    col01 varchar(max),
    col02 varchar(max),
    col03 varchar(max),
    col04 varchar(max),
    col05 varchar(max),
    col06 varchar(max),
    col07 varchar(max),
    col08 varchar(max),
    col09 varchar(max),
    col10 varchar(max),
    col11 varchar(max),
    col12 varchar(max),
    col13 varchar(max),
    col14 varchar(max),
    col15 varchar(max),
    col16 varchar(max),
    col17 varchar(max)
);

bulk insert dbo.CsvImport from 'C:\Temp\CsvImport.csv' with (
    rowterminator='0x0A',
    fieldterminator=',',
    datafiletype = 'char',
    firstrow = 2
);

select * from dbo.CsvImport;
```

This yields the following, perhaps unexpect, output:

| col01 | col02 | col03 | col04 | col05 | col06 | col07 | col08 | col09 | col10 | col11 | col12 | col13 | col14 | col15 | col16 | col17 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| alph01 | alph02 | alph03 | alph04 | alph05 | alph06 | alph07 | alph08 | alph09 | alph10 | alph11 | alph12 | alph13 | alph14 | alph15 | alph16 | alph17 |
| brav01 | brav02 | brav03 | brav04 | brav05 char01 | char02 | char03 | char04 | char05 | char06 | char07 | char08 | char09 | char10 | char11 | char12 | char13,char14,char15,char16,char17 |

Comment: You have my sincerest apologies.  The other file had two row types, 5 and 10.  Once I dumped them into their respective perm tables, it gave the appearance that it worked, but in actuality, it did exactly like you said.  Thank you for taking the time and the work to lead this horse to the water.  I've been looking at this problem for so long I didn't see what was right in front of me.